# Denying direct access to a folder (only allow through app)

Tags: asp.net, security, file-access

I need to prevent someone from directly accessing a pdf, instead only allowing them to be pulled through the app itself. How can this be done?

Comment: Is this application hosted on a server you control or on a server under someone else's control, such as a third-party hosting company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are two solutions for doing that:
>
> 1- You can put your “UsersUploads” folder outside the website
> directory, so if your website exist on “c:\website\example.com” you
> can put the “UsersUploads” there “c:\UsersUploads”, Like that IIS has
> no control over this folder and its files, And your website code will
> still have access to this directory as a normal physical path.
>
> 2- Stop IIS from serving this folder:
>
> IIS by default doesn’t server some website folders and files such
> App_Data, App_Code, bin, App_GlobalResourses, App_LocalResources,
> Web.config,….

Comment: 3 - create the folder under your web app & untick read from the folder in IIS manager.

Comment: 4- if you're using IIS 7, create the folder under your web app & add a request filter to the web.config to prevent access to the folder. This is what IIS does to it's folders, eg App_Data

Comment: This helps me too. When I log on to my server, let's say through FTP, I get 2 folders appear, WWW and PRIVATE. Can I put my downloads folder in there so nobody apart from my script can access it?

Answer (score 13):

Add this to your top-level Web.config to block a folder called Reports (your folder name goes there).
This will allow your application to access Reports/file.pdf but an outside request to yoursite.com/Reports/file.pdf will be blocked.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>   
         <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <hiddenSegments>
              <add segment="Reports" />
            </hiddenSegments>
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: this code will deny access for everyone, then how users can access files?

Comment: @سید رضا دادرضایی - your page handler can check their authorization then write the file to the response or use Response.TransmitFile

Answer (score 0):

Put the files in the `app_data` folder and then use a `HttpHandler` to serve the files. You can use url rewriting if you want to hide it and make it look cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

set the permissions on the folder to deny access to whoever.  Ask your sys admin guy to create an account and give read access to the folder.  Then set impersonation up in the web.config file to use the new account.

Read this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(VS.71).aspx

Comment: There's better simpler ways than changing file permissions

Comment: Impersonation has significant overhead in IIS and causes very bad performance with the Sql Client.