# How to Prevent direct access to files and folders in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have deployed a web application on IIS7 and the application has mail attachment files saved on webserver's `Attachments` folder and it's working fine when the attachment is downloaded from 
application.

The problem is when the same url viewed from Chrome is typed from a different machine the same can be viewed/downloaded. I tried couple of solution after googling but here the Attachments folder on webserver have security enabled for Network services.

`http://machine-121/AdminManagement/Attachments/58501/17112014131251/FilledForm.pdf` (can be read)

I tried

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms"/>
<authorization>
<deny users="?"/>  <!--This will restrict anonymous user access-->
</authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="login.aspx"> <!-- Path of your Registration.aspx page -->
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="*"/> <!-- This will allow users to access to everyone to Registeration.aspx--> 
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```

but couldn't succeed any suggestion/help would be of great help.

Comment: I wouldn't expose those files directly. I'd have all requests go through a central function which takes the username and the filename (ID?) and determines whether they should be able to get the file. If so just use Repsonse to send them the file directly - not direct link used.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Appriciate if you can point to some reference link for the same.

Comment: you want to use  sth like "request filtering"  in web.cofig.   if so check the   bottom answer  by user1160006  in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822173/denying-direct-access-to-a-folder-only-allow-through-app#answer-20359486    .

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `.pdf` extension isn't caught by the ASP.NET handlers, since that isn't a file type that is mapped to ASPNET_ISAPI (aka the [ASP.NET HTTP Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479328.aspx)). Hence the filtering in your `web.config` file doesn't apply to those files.

You have two options:

1. Map all file extensions (or at least pdf files in this case) to ASPNET_ISAPI using the IIS configuration panel. Note that this will increase the load on your server since the overhead of IIS on itself is lower than IIS + ASP.NET;
2. Use an HTTP handler that gets the file for you. This allows you to do some fine grained authorization checks on the file access too. See the [Introduction to HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks Patrick for you suggestions and wanted to know what if I use Impersonatio...

Comment: I think the last part of your sentence is missing.

Comment: its just asking to use  "Impersonation"

Comment: What do you intend to do with it? Still all above rules apply.

Comment: Patrick as per you suggestion I mapped the *.pdf to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll on IIS 7.5 but now I am get a blank window when accessing though application or direct URL is there something I am missing pls help

Comment: I will set up an environment myself and check this for you. May take some time.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this problem is the create a HTTP Handler in which you can restrict download files based on certain conditions. check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544289/Restricting-files-download-using-HTTP-Handler-base) for more information

Comment: Thanks Ghyath, your solution seems tobe ideal but just want to confirm that the link http://machine-121/AdminManagement/Attachments/58501/FilledForm.pdf is being used both by admin and client site will updating the web.config of respective webserver serve the purpose.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not get what you mean exactly.
More explanation please.

Comment: I mean will the http handler module be deployed only on the webserver which has folder with file as it is being accessed from client as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do is add the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests attribute to your modules section in web.config, like so:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> 
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Brandon, tried you suggestion but couldn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Hum very strange. I use this all the time. It should restrict access to all files (not just .aspx) based on your authorization settings. Is it not doing that? You are able to get to the pdf file without authenticating?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to block XML direct access in IIS and still allowing the app to query the file with the following rule:

```
<rule name="Prevent XML direct access" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*filename\.xml$" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^part_of_query.*$" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="/error" appendQueryString="false" />
```