# How prevent direct downloading files from server using URL in ASP.Net MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, iis, authorization

I've checked many questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968328/how-to-prevent-direct-access-to-files-and-folders-in-asp-net) but I didn't find my answer.
There are some files in the root folder of my project (user uploaded files, scripts and Styles, ...).
I'm looking for a solution to prevent users from downloading specific files directly by entering the URL in the browser address bar (because of software security issues). I mean even the authorized users who logged in and have access to some pages of the application, They are not allowed to download some contents directly from the server.

obviously, it is important the solution should not prevent the proper functionality of scripts, styles, etc.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
 In other words, I only want to exclude access to some user created reports in .pdf format, user uploaded .zip files, .xls template files, etc from direct download.

Comment: You can't make things available that are needed by the application, such as scripts and styles but not have them downloadable. The user is technically downloading them by URL when they view the page. If you want files to be restricted, never sit them within the site. User uploaded files should go outside the website/application into their own directory and be uploaded/downloaded through a gatekeeper function that can verify permissions, etc.. That way the user would have to identify how to format a url to retrieve the file, but since code is in the way it can determine if access is possible.

Comment: What @MarkFitzpatrick said ^^^ . Whatever ends up being rendered in the browser is just a resource that can be downloaded...and is in fact already downloaded. All it takes is for users to hit F12 (say, in Chrome) and poke around the sources tab to discover your assets and save them locally.

Comment: Dear @MarkFitzpatrick & Kev, I've updated my question to clarify my question. Many Thanks :)