# Turn off/on access to a file with documents

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-access

I'm building an ASP.NET C# website, one of the files contains Word Docs and PDF files which I want to block access to, unless they know the password. I tried the FileIOPermission Class using full path and relative path with no luck.

```
FileIOPermission f2 = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.NoAccess, @"resources");
f2.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess.NoAccess | FileIOPermissionAccess.NoAccess, @"resources");
try
{
    f2.Demand();
}
catch (SecurityException s)
{
    //Console.WriteLine(s.Message);
}

Response.Redirect(@"resources/20019_05_05_DOCS.zip");
```

I am testing the code, expecting to get access denied, but I can still access the files in the resource folder . Thank you.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this prior question here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/26968328/125981 or this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/6822173/125981 Or, even this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/528858/125981   So, perhaps you simply need to put the file in the proper folder?

Comment: Thank you for the links, however, I don't want the files permanently hidden. I want the files to default hidden, provide password allow access, then hide them again.

Comment: It sounds as if you want a authorization filter - 'Authorization (preventing access to resources a user isn't authorized for)' in combination with a resource filter which runs after that... here is an overview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved this problem.
Hide your files in App_Data. 
If user's password is correct, 
fetch the file using byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)
Provide the doc using  return new FileContentResult(byteArray, MimeType);

the end